# How to transform file (using SED)?

Tags: sed

I have a file (10k lines) in format:

line_number string
i.e.

```
1 string1
2 string2
...
10000 string10000
```

How to transform it to format like this
the_same_constant_for_all_lines string
i.e.

```
101 string1
101 string2
...
101 string10000
```

It is file in Windows but I can use SED, may be it is easier.

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work?

Comment: I have asked about help because I have no solution :-)

Comment: The [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) could be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use sed, try this

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/101 \2/g' <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
awk '{print "101 " $2}' file
```

or you can use this

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print "101 " $i}' file
```

Comment: I have got awk here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm but it gives me an error: E:\MyProjects\tr>awk '{print "101 " $2}' ti.txt
awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression